# Get uri from cached video ExoPlayer

Tags: android, caching, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have a question about `ExoPlayer` and caching. Struggling with this for a 2 days already and searched over the internet but I can't collect all informations together in one picture, don't know is that even possible. So my question is:

**Can somehow using `ExoPlayer` components like `CacheDataSource`, `CacheUtils` etc, video be cached and than `Uri` of that video retrieved? Like independently from `ExoPlayer`**

I tried with `DataSpec`, `CacheUtil`, `SimpleCache` but didn't find a way to do this.

I don't know is that a simple question or maybe it is not possible at all. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hi! If you find solution, can you please post it here?

Answer (score -1):

if you are using the simplecache then you can retrieve all url as keys of cache like below:

```
abc.getcache(context).getKeys();
```

This will return you all the urls whose data is cached in you app cache.

if you want the video to be cached then see the exoplayer video of google 2018.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svdq1BWl4r8.